Lambda calling AWS Textract - is there any way to limit Textract to specific S3 buckets?
So I have a Lambda which has an IAM role that allows read and write access from a specific S3 bucket. I am triggering textract:DetectDocumentText which reads from one of these buckets. I want to limit Textract to only be able to access this bucket. I know Textract doesnt have ServiceLinked roles. Is there anyway to limit Textract permissions to just this bucket or does it "inherit" the bucket permissons from the Lambda?
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "textract:DetectDocumentText"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
},
{
    "Sid": "AllS3",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-foot-bucket"
    ]
}


Since Textract uses the permissions of the caller, in your case the Execution Role of the Lambda, this is not straightforward. If the Lambda needs access to multiple buckets, we can't use the same role to also make the Textract call.
What you can do, is create another role TextractAccessor that has permission to do the Textract actions and also has access to the S3 bucket that Textract may use.
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "textract:DetectDocumentText"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
},
{
    "Sid": "SingleS3Bucket",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:*Object"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<textract-only-bucket>"
    ]
}

You can the grant your Lambda's execution role permission to call sts:AssumeRole on TextractAccessor. In your code, you'll then assume the TextractAccessor role and use the credentials returned by STS (you can cache these) to make the API call to Textract. It's a bit annoying, but this way to clearly segregate the permissions between Textract and the rest of the Lambda function.

thanks - in order to limit the textract calls to a single s3 bucket -> if we DIDNT create a new role but used the originating Lambda role -> would the s3 bucket polices limiting access just this role be sufficient to prevent others from doing "Textract" on our bucket?

I may have misunderstood your question. Are you trying to restrict anyone except the Lambda's execution role from using Textract with data in that bucket?

correct....exactly thats what im trying to do

You can deny access to anyone not using that role, but you can't restrict it to requests via Textract, because the aws:CalledVia condition doesn't support Textract. I could thing of strategies to approach this, but at that point it's probably easier to put the bucket and textract in their own separate AWS account. Maybe this is an xy problem, what are you really after? Please add a bit of context about why you're doing this.

What you're saying is i think where Im headed. If I have a Lambda with role LambdaRole which has access to a bucket foo-bucket & foo-bucket has a policy that restricts read/write access to that Lambda: The is it correct to say that ONLY the Textract API calls ORIGINATING from our lambda that read from that bucket have permissions to read data from that bucket - and no other Textract calls from any other Lambda/ECS etc can access our data?

Yes, that basically means that the S3 bucket will become useless to anyone not having that role, which may or may not be what you intend. Just be very careful not to lock yourself out - denies are tricky... https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access

This is great...locking down S3 to Textract calls from the Lambda and avoiding any other calls (textract or otherwise)  being able to call that bucket is precicelsy what I needed! thanks
